# Spark : ClassCastException while converting string into date

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I am trying to read `parquet` file in dataframe with following code:

```
val data = spark.read.schema(schema)
        .option("dateFormat", "YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss").parquet(<file_path>)

data.show()
```

Here's the schema:

```
def schema: StructType = StructType(Array[StructField](
    StructField("id", StringType, false),
    StructField("text", StringType, false),
    StructField("created_date", DateType, false)
    ))
```

When I try to execute `data.show()`, it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableInt.update(SpecificInternalRow.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificInternalRow.update(SpecificInternalRow.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRowConverter$RowUpdater.set(ParquetRowConverter.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetPrimitiveConverter.addBinary(ParquetRowConverter.scala:89)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$2$6.writeValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.writeCurrentValueToConverter(ColumnReaderImpl.java:372)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.read(RecordReaderImplementation.java:405)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:198)
```

Apparently, it's because of date format and `DateType` in my schema. If I change `DateType` to `StringType`, it works fine and outputs the following:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|                  id|                text|          created_date|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|id..................|text................|2017-01-01T00:08:09Z|
```

I want to read `created_date` into `DateType`, do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Your sample shows an ISO timestamp *with timezone* (`Z` = Zero offset = `+00:00`= `UTC` = `GMT`) but your input format does not mention the final `X` to handle the time zone >> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have tried with `YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss`, `YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ` and `YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX` but the result is still the same. I guess it has something to do with byte array to date conversion.

Comment: My own guess is that the `ParquetRowConverter` class was never tested against `dateFormat` option... So you have to read the file in a DataFrame, then convert the field by constructing a second DataFrame from the first. Is that really a problem? With a bit of luck, the *"lazy evaluation"* mantra means that the conversion will be done at read time, anyway...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter that's absolutely fine. I am looping through `dataframe` in my code anyway, just thought that if there was somethingout of the box that I can use directly, I would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

The following works under Spark 2.1. Note the change of the date format and the usage of TimestampType instead of DateType.

```
val schema = StructType(Array[StructField](
  StructField("id", StringType, false),
  StructField("text", StringType, false),
  StructField("created_date", TimestampType, false)
))

val data = spark
  .read
  .schema(schema)
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
  .parquet("s3a://thisisnotabucket")
```

In older versions of Spark (I can confirm this works under 1.5.2), you can create a UDF to do the conversion for you in SQL.

```
def cvtDt(d: String): java.sql.Date = { 
  val fmt = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
  new java.sql.Date(fmt.parseDateTime(d).getMillis)
}

def cvtTs(d: String): java.sql.Timestamp = {
  val fmt = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
  new java.sql.Timestamp(fmt.parseDateTime(d).getMillis)
}

sqlContext.udf.register("mkdate", cvtDt(_: String))
sqlContext.udf.register("mktimestamp", cvtTs(_: String))

sqlContext.read.parquet("s3a://thisisnotabucket").registerTempTable("dttest")

val query = "select *, mkdate(created_date), mktimestamp(created_date) from dttest"
sqlContext.sql(query).collect.foreach(println)
```

NOTE: I did this in the REPL, so I had to create the DateTimeFormat pattern on every call to the cvt* methods to avoid serialization issues. If you're doing this is an application, I recommend extracting the formatter into an object.

```
object DtFmt {
  val fmt = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T‌​'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this throws `java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Timestamps (with nanoseconds) are expected to be stored in 12-byte long binaries, but got a 20-byte binary.`. I guess I need to create a new column (once I read the dataframe) and convert string to date explicitly as date is stored as string in parquet.